# Error : [ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero]

Tags: python

I get ZeroDivisionError: float division Any value below one gives errors.

```
def get_accuracy(antibodies, test_data, self_class, non_self_class):
    correct = 0.0
    incorrect = 0.0
    for x in test_data:
        yhat = predict(antibodies, x, self_class, non_self_class )
        if x[0] == yhat:
            correct += 1
        else:
            incorrect += 1
    accuracy = correct / float(len(test_data))
    return accuracy
```

---

Traceback (most recent call last):
accuracy = correct / float(len(test_data))

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Comment: test test_data with an if ... if test_data==0: . define what you want as a return value.
But it seems test_data length should not be 0.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the test data size is zero.

You can check it by printing the info about the test_data.

```
print(len(test_data))
```